# passing variable to multiple classes - C++

Tags: c++, oop, sdl

i'm new and still learning OOP and SDL for educational purpose.

so, i have a variable `SDL_Renderer renderer`. this variable needs to be initiated only once, and i initiate it in `GameManager` class.
and i have another class named `Texture` that needs that `renderer`.
this `Texture` will be used frequently.

so how do i pass this `renderer`? do i have to call `GameManager` in the `Texture` class? but if i do that, it means that i make`GameManager` everytime i use the `Texture` right? or there is another way around?

thank you for helping me, i'm really sorry if my question is vague or not clear.

**EDIT**

this is Texture class

```
class Texture
{
public:
    Texture();
    ~Texture();

    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
    bool loadFromFile(std::string path);
    bool loadTextFromFile(std::string text, SDL_Color textColor, TTF_Font* font);
    void render(int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL);
    void free();

    bool lockTexture();
    bool unlockTexture();
    void* getPixels();
    int getPitch();

private:
    int vWidth;
    int vHeight;
    SDL_Texture* vTexture;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

    void* pPixels;
    int pPitch;
};
```

this is the initiator

```
Texture::Texture()
{
    vTexture = NULL;
    vWidth = 0;
    vHeight = 0;
    renderer = GameManager::getRenderer();
}
```

this is GameManager class

```
class GameManager
{
public:
    GameManager();
    ~GameManager();
    bool intializeGame();
    void gameLoop();
    static SDL_Renderer* getRenderer();

private:
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    static SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    TTF_Font* font = NULL;

    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
};
```

the `getRenderer()` just a getter to pass the renderer

and this is my Main

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    GameManager gameManager;
    gameManager.intializeGame();

    Texture charTexture;
    SDL_Rect rect;

    bool text = charTexture.loadFromFile("foo.png");
    if (!text)
    {
        printf("texture not loaded");
    }

    rect.x = 0;
    rect.y = 0;
    rect.w = charTexture.getWidth();
    rect.h = charTexture.getHeight();

    while (true)
    {

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(GameManager::getRenderer(), 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        SDL_RenderClear(GameManager::getRenderer());

        charTexture.render(10, 10, &rect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(GameManager::getRenderer());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i hope it's not confusing.

Comment: You could pass a reference to it in texture's constructor. I don't know SDL but there's probably some good books on how to design a SDL program.

Comment: The question you want to ask yourself is : Who owns `renderer` ? Then we can talk about how to pass it around.

Comment: the `renderer` is in GameManager class. is that counted as owning? @NeilKirk there is simple tutorial by LazyFoo. but it's not too OO i think. it's fairly straight forward. and uses lot global variable

Comment: The owner is the one who is responsible for cleaning-up (and most of the time for creation too). In this case GameManager is probably a good owner since I suppose by its name that it lives for the whole duration of the program and you will need the renderer for that period.

Comment: yes `GameManager` is going to live the as long as the program runs. i put the game loop and input handler there.

Comment: To me it makes more sense to pass textures to a rendering class than to call a render function on a texture

Comment: i thought of that too. but in order to initialize and create texture it needs the renderer in the first place. because of this `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface)`, it takes renderer as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I've never used SDL. This might be terrible, but it's based on what you gave me.
The important thing is the ownership. This is a shared ownership example. It's quite simple and takes the burden of figuring out when to destroy SDL_Renderer off of you.

```
class GameManager {

//BLABGLABLA

public:
    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Renderer> getRenderer();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Renderer> renderer
}


class Texture 
{
public:
    Texture(std::shared_ptr<SDL_Renderer> theRenderer, //some other args)

private:
    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Renderer> renderer;
}
```

So based on the name of the classes alone, you probably want GameManager to own the renderer, but you also want Texture to have access to it.
One way you can do that is to have a `shared_ptr` member in both classes, and to pass the renderer to texture in its constructor.

Basically the renderer object you initialized in GameManager, will only be destroyed when the last `shared_ptr` pointing to it is destroyed.

Comment: i just tried using `static` pointer to pass from `GameManager` to `Texture` class. it works. but, if i use static do i still call the whole class? or just that specific `static` variable? beacuse `GameManager` is basically a really big  class. i think it's not good to call it over and over again, when truthfully i just need it once.

Comment: Wow wait... what ? Who told you about `static` anything ? I don't think static means what you think it means. Can you show me the code you have right now by editing your question. COpy paste the code from your editor, I'll fix the indentation if it is too terrible don't worry;

Comment: @user3189174   And to be fair `static`can mean 2 completely different things depending on the context in C++.

Comment: @user3189174 Also and that is probably the most important thing for your design : who creates `Texture`instances ?

Comment: sorry for late reply, my friend told me that i could use `static` but he did warn me that it would just like calling the whole class in runtime. i'll post my code.

Comment: and it displays the thing that i need. but i'm sure this is not the good way to do it.